# Unable to set a field in static sublist

Tags: suitescript

all
 i am trying to set a field in a static sublist in client script 1.0 but i was unable to get through. Any help is appreciated.

```
if(Status==value)
{
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody58','nsajfnjs');
    nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i, 3);
    nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'itemreceive', i, true);
    alert('i'+i);
    found=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to set a value on a NS sublist:

1 )

- nlapiSelectLineItem
- nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue
- nlapiCommitLineItem

2)

- nlapiSetLineItemValue

If none of them work then it might be the sublist is not editable or you need to enable the fields before setting the values.

Comment: so,is it possible to change a field in static sublist in client script? @felipechang